# Why am I getting no data when using PHP API on wordpress page?

Tags: civievent, api

CiviCRM 4.6.6 Wordpress 4.2.4

The code in my wordpress page:

```
[insert_php]
// Perform bootstrap
civicrm_initialize();

$result = civicrm_api3('Event', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "title,summary,custom_31",
  'event_type_id' => "",
));

print_r($result);
[/insert_php]
```

the ouput on my page:

```
Array
(
[is_error] => 0
[version] => 3
[count] => 0
[values] => Array
(
)

)
```

There should be data.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just messed up with my code:

```
[insert_php]
// Perform bootstrap
civicrm_initialize();

$result = civicrm_api3('Event', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "title,summary,custom_31"
));

print_r($result);
[/insert_php]
```